# Can't enable DEBUG & VERBOSE for Huawei Android Logcat

Tags: android, logging, adb, verbose, huawei-mobile-services

I'm having [Huawei Nova Plus](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/mobile-phones/novaplus/index.htm) I just found that Huawei only displays in its Android log starting log level `INFO`. Of course I need `DEBUG & VERBOSE` in my development. I came across this [link](https://www.xda-developers.com/huawei-phones-disable-logcat-heres-how-to-restore-access/) which is exactly same screens appear to me and I mark the 3 check at the end for "`AP Log`", "`Charge Log`", & "`Sleep Log`" when I reboot my mobile, it still behaves the same and only logging is for INFO. I check the project menu again, and I found all log level not checked after reboot.

Appreciate help as really affecting my development.

Comment: Have the exact same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I contacted several site of Huawei, and simply noone answer, I'm still posting in other forums but no solution for now.

Comment: @JSONStatham I made a workaround in my code & switched from normal Android logging framework to [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) library & made a custom debug tree to write to file instead of normal Android log and it worked. I have shared the code [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FkyTI-X1-GIlChJTeEcG8qI87F2YHjXbtEVZyraHnis/edit?usp=sharing) if you need it. It will create a file "log.txt" in your application folder/files.

Comment: A friend of my also have Huawei Honor 7. He used the method you linked with an earlier version, and he was able to do it. I think they messed up something with a later update. :/

I also found a workaround by setting the loglevel through adb:

```adb logcat -s "TAGNAME"```

But its tedious to do this.

Comment: It seems so, I'm waiting for the new update emui 5 that will have Android Nougat, they may fix it. But quite surprised with the level of no support they are providing.

Comment: I made a post of this in my blog, where I used another code for Timber, inorder not to use a file but convert all DEBUG & VERBOSE to INFO so it is printed, [here is the link](http://ashraffouad.blogspot.com/2017/04/enable-debug-verbose-for-huawei-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

Followed the setup link. Don't reboot your phone, you will have the VERBOSE log right way.